# IAR Embedded workbench illegal opcode error

Tags: assembly, msp430

I write this code, the purpose is to return  = ∑A∙B, when A,B are 2 arrays of numbers in length of 8.

When the program gets to the RET command, there is an error:
"Illegal opcode found on address 0X0".
I can't figure out why does it happen.

```
    #include <msp430xG46x.h>     ;define controlled include file

         ORG 1100h
Arr1     DW   2,0,4,2,6,5,1,1  
Arr2     DW   3,0,8,5,2,9,3,7  
Size     DW   8         ; Arr length

var1     DS32  1

         RSEG   CODE                  ; ORG   0x3100 - place program in 'CODE' segment in to Flash memory
         RSEG   CSTACK

Main    
         MOV   #Arr1,R5
         MOV   #Arr2,R6
         MOV   Size,R7
         CLR   R8
Loop      
          call #Func
          DEC  R7
          JNZ  Loop
L1        JMP  L1

Func      
          MOV  @R5,R10            ;Adding @R6, @R5 times to R8 
          CLR  R4
          ADD  @R6,R4
L2       
          DEC  R10
          JZ   Result
          ADD  @R6,R4
          ADC  R9
          JMP  L2
Result    
          MOV  R4,var1
          MOV  #2,R11
          MOV  R9,var1(R11)
          ADD  var1,R8
          INCD R5
          INCD R6      
          RET

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          COMMON  INTVEC                  ; Interrupt Vectors
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

         ORG     RESET_VECTOR            ; POR, ext. Reset

         DW      Main

         END
```

Comment: Presumably you're executing a `RET` instruction at a point in time where you don't have a proper return address at the top of the stack. Use a debugger to find out how that might've happened. By the way, your multiplication seems incorrect. What if `A` is 0? (as it will be on one occasion with your test data).

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks I'll try to look at the return address.
After I'll get over I'll check again multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

1) SP register is not initialized so you'r pushing memory to 0x0000 that depending on your MCU could be anything. This make a mess with calls and rets too.

2) Your code is ending in stack segment as RSEG CSTACK come after RSEG CODE and before your code.

Change

```
    RSEG   CODE                  ; ORG   0x3100 - place program in 'CODE' segment in to Flash memory
    RSEG   CSTACK

Main
```

to

```
     RSEG   CSTACK
     RSEG   CODE                  ; ORG   0x3100 - place program in 'CODE' segment in to Flash memory

Main     MOV     #SFE(CSTACK), SP
```